How Powershell Handles an Invalid attribute
I am expecting below code to throw an error..since Get-Childitem does not have Lastaccessed
try{    

Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { -not $_.PsIsContainer -and $_.lastaccessed -lt $date} -ErrorAction stop  
Write-Host "hello:"  
}
catch{  
Write-Host $($_)  
}  


But to my surprise,it does not
i did try to search,but cant find any satisfactory answers

That is because $_.lastaccessed amounts to $null and therefore comparing it with -lt $someDateTime will always be True. P.S. You can omit -not $_.PsIsContainer if you append the -File switch to the Get-ChildItem cmd

You'd need to use Set-StrictMode for this to happen, more specifically version 2.0 or above:
Set-StrictMode -Version 2.0

If you look at the -Version parameter details you'd see:


2.0

Prohibits references to uninitialized variables. This includes uninitialized variables in strings.
Prohibits references to non-existent properties of an object.
Prohibits function calls that use the syntax for calling methods.




